# HAML - how to put regular text between links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I have a small HAML paragraph with links like this:

```
%p
  =link_to("My Disclosures", "#")
  =link_to("Create Disclosure", "#")
  =link_to("My Programs", "#") 
  =link_to("Log Out", "#")
```

What I want to do is to put a separator like this "|" between the links, but I am not sure how.  I tried putting it next to the text inside the "" but it became part of the link text.  When I tried putting the separators at the end of the line, it just didn't show up.

Any idea how I can get the serperating character to render as just text after a link?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just write the string itself on its own line:

```
%p
  =link_to("My Disclosures", "#")
  |
  =link_to("Create Disclosure", "#")
  |
  =link_to("My Programs", "#") 
  |
  =link_to("Log Out", "#")
```

Alternatively, you can append it to your output string:

```
%p
  =link_to("My Disclosures", "#") << '|'
  =link_to("Create Disclosure", "#") << '|'
  =link_to("My Programs", "#") << '|'
  =link_to("Log Out", "#")
```

Comment: Much prefer either the css or helper routes approach.  Views that start to have bits of this in them will deteriorate over time until they're a hodge-podge mess.

Comment: Me too, @MichaelDurrant.  I would have accepted [jdoe's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10250672/107277) over my own.

Answer (score 4):

I had the very same problem. This how I solved it:

1) in module ApplicationHelper:

```
def links_bar(join_with = ' | ', &block)
  capture{yield}.split("\n").join(join_with).html_safe
end
```

2) in any view:

```
= links_bar do
  = link_to("My Disclosures", "#")
  = link_to("Create Disclosure", "#")
  = link_to("My Programs", "#") 
  = link_to("Log Out", "#")
```

Generates:

```
<a href="#">My Disclosures</a> | <a href="#">Create Disclosure</a> | <a href="#">My Programs</a> | <a href="#">Log Out</a>
```

Am I crazy? ;)

Thanks to Semyon Perepelitsa for hints.

Comment: I would place the method into a helper module like ApplicationHelper, it doesn't have anything to do with the controller. Also, I don't understand the `block.binding.eval('self').capture{yield}` part, `capture(&block)` should work.

Comment: I just found it in a big dusty box. I can't remember why did I place it there but ) But I agree with you. I'll change my answer. `block...` part is needed because `capture` helper isn't available inside controllers. That's why I "fetched" view and applied `capture` to it.

Comment: Now I see. If you place it inside a helper then you don't need to do this because you are already in the view's context.

Comment: I guess I know why I placed it there! The commit in my testing app is named `view-context-in-controller`. Next commit is called: `adding-validations-on-the-fly`: controller adds validation to a model. Scary times )

Comment: +1, I like this answer better than my own, which was the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

In this instance you're going about things the wrong way.

A much more correct way to get the effect you are after would involve a little CSS:

```
ul.nav {
  list-style:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0
}

ul.nav li {
  margin:0;
  padding:0 0.5em;
  border-right:1px solid black
}

ul.nav li.last {
  border-right:none;
}

%ul.nav
  %li=link_to("My Disclosures", "#")
  %li=link_to("Create Disclosure", "#")
  %li=link_to("My Programs", "#") 
  %li.last=link_to("Log Out", "#")
```

This way you have a plain, semantically correct, accessible and search engine friendly list of links which converts to a styled list using the magic of CSS.

I am aware I am answering a different question to the one you asked, but you should be aware of the "correct" way to tackle this use case.